# Problem With the Digital Signature Very Important

Tags: apt, 10.04, application-development, certificates, web-development

We are using Ubuntu 10.04 and we have our internet portal that purpose we require digital certificate for authentication. We are using Firefox 24.0.

The certificate shows in Firefox's preferences but if I sign with digital certificate on our internet portal that certificate not show. error is :

> No certificate found . Digital certificate not detect on portal

We are using Java 7.51. Is there any package that needs to be installed on the system related Java or anything else to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 (for desktop use) and Firefox 24 are both ***dangerously old*** and unsupported. That would usually be cause enough to close the question but in this case I think it's pertinent enough to warrant an answer.

It seems possible, even likely, that one or both are using certificate definitions that are just too old to verify your certificate.

You need to upgrade to 12.04 or 14.04.

Comment: We cant upgrade the system